# Can I use WCF Data Annotations with OperationContract's arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, validation, data-annotations

I had a look at [this tutorial](https://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/) and decorated my DataContract's DataMembers with Data Annotations for validation purposes. The problem is I want to use this approach with some of my OperationContracts that don't use DataContracts but variables.

```
public int CreateUser([Required][MinLength(10)]string email, string password)
{
    //...
}
```

I tried passing bad data to the CreateUser method, but the data was accepted, even though I passed an email, the length of which was less than 10 characters. So, can I use Data Annotations with OperationContract's arguments and if I can, how?

Comment: Googling for wcf data annotations reveals multiple interesting results including this https://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com

Comment: I've already put this link in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class and decorate its's properties.

```
public class LogonInfo
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(10)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And then use that as a parameter for your method.

```
public int CreateUser(LogonInfo info)
{
}
```